# How to fix gradle eclipse plugin to use correct JRE when importing gradle project?

Tags: gradle

Currently, I can run ./gradlew eclipse and create the eclipse project and that works great in that it uses JavaSE-1.8.  Unfortunately, I have 12 projects and don't really feel like loading each one at a time.

The issue though is when I use the gradle eclipse plugin and import the project, it decides to use JavaSE-1.7 which I did 'used' to use.  I can't seem to find a quick setting in the gradle plugin, though it would be even nicer if I could just put the info in the build.gradle file for everyone to use.

The following code blew up in my face when I imported the project..
https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-3100

Well, the .remove method blew up.  Removing that resulted in ending up in 1.7 even though I put 1.8.

I am using gradle-2.11-bin.zip

UPDATE: I removed the '' replacing with single ' so that it doesn't throw an exception but still loads 1.7.  To work around this issue, I load with gradle plugin and then run ./gradlew eclipse and then collapse all projects and using the shift key, I then select all projects and refresh and it moves to 1.8 (so the gradlew eclipse works while the gradle plugin doesn't :(  they must be different code path).

Comment: Can you maybe post the error message when the .remove method blows up?

Comment: well, there was a typo of '' that I didn't notice.  Now it loads but still loads with 1.7 :(.  Man, this really sucks.  Then, I run ./gradlew eclipse and refresh all 12 projects and it has TWO 1.8's attached.